# Bounded Matrix-Vector Multiplication

Tags: matrices, self-learning

Given a $p\times p$ square matrix $A$. Can I say that the 2 norm of their product is always bounded for any $p \times 1$ vector, please? That is,

$$
\| Ax \| <\infty, \forall x\in\mathbb R^p.
$$

A book I am reading says something like the above. It sounds right. However, I am not sure whether it is correct since I did not see such claim before. Could anyone explain a bit, please? Thank you!

Comment: Why do you write $x \in \Bbb R^p \times \Bbb R^1 = \Bbb R^{p + 1}$?  A $p \times 1$ vector $x \in \Bbb R^p$!  Cheers!

Comment: The way you word it, then yes, but it would be a simple consequence of the fact that the norm is well defined for any vector. Are you sure it is what you meant?

Comment: @RobertLewis Thanks. I corrected the error.

Comment: @MBW I think so. I am a bit unsure since it is quite simple.

Comment: $Ax$ is a vector, so its norm $\| Ax\|$ is a well-defined real number. If you are asking about the boundedness of the set $B=\{\| Ax\| :x\in \Bbb R^p\}$, then $B$ is bounded if and only if $A=0$.

Comment: @SRX I think so. Isn't it?

Comment: Zircht: I don't think the condition you proposed on boundedness includes all possibilities. $\| Ax \|$ will, in fact, be always bounded for given conditions. You may want to check the explanation below in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Page 4-6 through 4-8 in [this document](http://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/course/math3230b/matrix%20norm.pdf) give a detailed derivation to prove the following:
$$
\| Ax \| <\boldsymbol{K}\| x \|, \forall x\in\mathbb R^p
$$
where, $\boldsymbol{K}=\sqrt{\sigma^2_1}$,

In other words $\boldsymbol{K}$ is the square root of the largest eigenvalue of $A\times A$ that will always be real-valued and non-negative. Hence, the above product is always bounded.